# How can I fix my .htaccess to resolve URLs that don't end in slashes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am using wordpress and use custom permalink structure: /%category%/%postname%/

My problem is that a decent number of people link to the site without including the trailing slash in the URL, so users get a 404 page.

I'm using the default .htaccess file that comes with wordpress because no solution I've tried has worked. I've tried using the Redirection plugin, with no success.

I'd gladly link to the site, but I don't want it to be construed as self-promotion. If you ask, I'll provide a link.

Could anyone help me find a plugin or provide some .htaccess entries to help resolve this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good reference for all things .htaccess is PerishablePress.com

http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
/%category%/%postname%(/?)
```

in your .htaccess file.

The question mark denotes an optional character sequence.

Comment: No need for the parentheses, unless you're planning on passing whether or not there's a / as a GET variable.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how to use that in .htaccess. /%category%/%postname%/ is being used under the settings tab of the wordpress admin interface, not in .htaccess. Is it possible to use regex within the permalink settings?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^(([^\/]+\/)*[^\/\.]+)$ $1/
```

Comment: I would imagine it's already enabled if the permalinks specified in the question work.